# how to set environment variables CAIROMM_CFLAGS and CAIROMM_LIBS

Tags: path, homebrew, configure, anaconda

While I remain ignorant how precisely Mac OS suddenly figured to find the dependencies (that was `brew`-installed) required to install `graph-tool` using `conda install` command...

I further remain unenlightened as to how to interpret the following msg and address it.

[image]

Tried:

1. Adding to `.bash_profile` `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH://anaconda/pkgs` accordingly the directory where there is cairomm installed..
2. `./configure -with--CAIROMM_CFLAGS -with--CAIROMM_LIBS`

Thank you for your comment (in advance)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got the general idea to `./configure -CAIROMM_CFLAGS=""` or the like,

Troubleshooting on `config.log` and some shell script language understanding

https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#macos-x